# How Can I make a element do something again on click

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, move

I need to have my ball jump again when I click, it, but I don't know how to put my functions together to make it do a jump again. Can anyone please help me with this? I repeat, I need the ball to jump agin when I click, and it needs to be able to do this in the air, no bounce needed.

```
var canvas, ctx, container;
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ball;
var vy;
var gravity = 0.5;
var bounce = 0.7;
var xFriction = 0.1;


function init() {
  setupCanvas();
  vy = (Math.random() * -15) + -5;
  ball = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: 100,
  radius: 20,
  status: 0,
  color: "red"
  };
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath()
  ballMovement();
}
setInterval(draw, 1000 / 35);

function ballMovement() {
  ball.y += vy;
  vy += gravity;
  if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width || ball.x - ball.radius < 0) {
  vx *= -1;
}

 if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height) {
 ball.y = canvas.height - ball.radius;
 vy *= -bounce;

 vy = 0;

 if (Math.abs(vx) < 1.1)
 vx = 0;
 xF();
 }
}

function setupCanvas() { //setup canvas
  container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = "container";
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  container.appendChild(canvas);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
}
```

I need it to be able to jump in the air, and it to be able to fall down a gain to a halting stop.

Comment: I would recommend plugging your code into JSFiddle.net and see how it runs. You have a few errors you may want to look at first.

Comment: Can you point them out, because I am still a beginner, a kid that is not even a teenager, and I have no idea how to use JSFiddle